# A property of minimal prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$  be a commutative ring with $1$, and let $\frak{p}$  be a minimal prime ideal of $R$. If $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq I_1\cap I_2$, where $I_1$ and $I_2$ are two ideals of $R$, can we deduce that $ \mathfrak{p}\subseteq I_1 $  or $ \mathfrak{p}\subseteq  I_2 $?

Comment: This is confusing.  If $\frak{p}\subseteq \mathrm{I}_1\cap \mathrm{I}_2$, then both $\frak{p}\subseteq \mathrm{I}_1$ and $\frak{p}\subseteq \mathrm{I}_2$.

Comment: Perhaps you meant $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq I_{1} \cup I_{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

It's obvious, and $\mathfrak p$ doesn't have to be prime for that: $I_1\cap I_2\subset I_1$, for instance.